# Replacement for a 74ACQ inverter

Tags: adc, buffer

I'm looking at the datasheet for the TI [adc12dl080](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc12dl080.pdf), it suggests a "quiet" 74ACQ series inverter to complement an output clock signal, presumably to reduce noise coupled into the ADC:

[image: example circuit]

Looking online, I see that these were introduced by the early 1990s, but I can't find a datasheet for that specific part or a way to buy one.  It isn't clear to me how much being "quiet" matters and without a datasheet I'm not sure how to pick something equivalent.  <s>Would a more common 74AC be acceptable here?</s> Actually, elsewhere in the datasheet:

> The best logic family to use in systems with A/D converters is one which employs non-saturating transistor designs, or has low noise characteristics, such as the 74LS, 74HC(T) and 74AC(T)Q families. The worst noise generators are logic families that draw the largest supply current transients during clock or signal edges, like the 74F and the 74AC(T) families.

So I should not use the 74AC, and I should find a low noise logic device.  The 74HC04 and 74LS04 are easier to find, but they're too slow, so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the datasheet for 74ACQ244 https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/74ACQ244-17733.pdf I would guess that the ACQ part has been specified because the skew (difference in propagation times for different gates on the same device) is low.  This probably won't be critical for the part of the schematic you've shown, but possibly it matters for the other three gates in the device (assuming they are used elsewhere in the circuit).  The datasheet claims that ACQ has quicker propagation times than AC, but in fact the differences appear to be minimal.

Comment: Only one of the inputs is hooked up, so skew isn't important. Presumably they picked a 4 channel device because a 1 channel wasn't available in the "quiet" version.

Answer (score 0):

this is 30 yr old technology which been improved over time.

your assumptions are not justified and require comparing test methods and specs.

[this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cy74fct646t.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1609131279276) CY74FCT646T octal tri-state buffer has speeds all less than or equal to 9 ns for a defined load capacitance.

[- most of the 74LVC family ought to meet your requirements](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/logic-gates-and-inverters/705?s=N4IgjCBcoEwOwDYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2uDGGDAAwjEAsAHCwJxyMgCsAzGA7cePOImFwW9YQnZgkxBGD58m3eezp0F4WXTDt1Mfjx30YLOH3Vwm1FiAC6xAA4AXKCADKbgE4BLADsAcxAAX2IwERhkEDRILDwiUgoQBB52HjViW2UdXL4uYhhOdgQzTiYmIpA%2BOn5C7jqGmOKWHjA6VpALVi1uXuVrNrq6GpKmcodiuDGYYZ64anqBuGUWbJ72SfSB7fLx2QQhNpp%2BAZYz7uMBcWKeaiYF4yYeOkNTqIhi1XZtgdU7028z4ImmPQQs0uAw6CDo4JB9WufHmZQB8PYz1YnCxHFsAxoVXGnRY%2BgJ8P6xU6cD%2B5Ooz061Gu70KwPhrGe2k0bLgWTM7KkAy5dE5SiWAwstAYkVJtAWgn0MG6YBpgnlkkKPBsVhpNgQqi1kV5Y2%2B4Fs8PBKrqryF83OkUKoMtAm2CyUNFNGT4mgk%2Bq4zhA7k8PgCIXCkXYQmgcQwOAIxDIkEoDADQcg3j8QVCERAAFoYtH4n4AK7JROUD68JyuDzp8I5rXRlxQMCuZuQTp0MJhIA)

- the original buffer was rated over a 40% range of Vcc/2 which covers their +/-18%  or 0.9V of 5V variance of the Vdd/2 threshold at 125mV/ns.
- This means 8ns/V slew rate or 16ns over a 2V range and 32ns from 10% to 90% .

there are more details to compare, yet I see no reason why speed is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly looks fast enough.  What makes the LVC family lower noise than the (apparently unsuitably noisy) 74AC?

Comment: 50 ohm drivers in smaller lithography in 5V family and 25 Ohm drivers in 3.6Vmax family